# Return Dictionary from Function or Sub in VBA

Tags: function, excel, dictionary, subroutine, vba

I would like to create and initialize a Dictionary object in one sub/function and use it in another.  I could do everything in the same sub but would like to have the code modularized.  This returns "argument not optional" which is the latest error in the latest version of this code that I have tried.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Function CreateDictionary() As Dictionary


Set aDictionary = New Dictionary

With aDictionary

    .Add Key:="key1", Item:="value1"
    .Add Key:="key2", Item:="value2"


End With


CreateDictionary = aDictionary
End Function

Sub useDictionary()

myDictionary = CreateDictionary

For Each k In myDictionary.Keys
    MsgBox myDictionary.k
Next



End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

1) `CreateDictionary = aDictionary` should be `Set CreateDictionary = aDictionary`
2) `myDictionary = CreateDictionary` should be `Set myDictionary = CreateDictionary`
3) `MsgBox myDictionary.k` should be `MsgBox myDictionary(k)`

Correct code:

```
Function CreateDictionary() As Dictionary
    Dim aDictionary As Dictionary
    Set aDictionary = New Dictionary

    With aDictionary
        .Add Key:="key1", Item:="value1"
        .Add Key:="key2", Item:="value2"
    End With

    Set CreateDictionary = aDictionary
End Function

Sub useDictionary()
    Dim myDictionary As Dictionary

    Set myDictionary = CreateDictionary

    For Each k In myDictionary.Keys
        MsgBox myDictionary(k)
    Next
End Sub
```